# Rails 4 cocoon ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

```
  <%= simple_form_for @order, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :contact %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :products do |product| %>
  <%= render 'product_fields', :f => product %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add product', f, :products %>
 <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
 <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
            orders_path, :class => 'btn' %>
 <% end %>
```

product_field_for

```
<%= f.input :name %>
```

and

```
def create
@order = Order.new(order_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:contact, { :products => [:id, :name, :description, :success, :count, :spot, :janpan_price, :taiwan_price, :_destroy ]}).merge(:seller_id => current_seller.id)
end
```

in the model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :seller
has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order 
end
```

but when I submit create

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in OrdersController#create
Product(#70251926707520) expected, got Array(#70251924853020)

```
1 # POST /orders.json

2 def create

3 @order = Order.new(order_params)

4 respond_to do |format|

5 if @order.save
```

it will broken at line 3

server log

```
    Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-13 18:49:37 +0800
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gHR42nO/ivCaOOGdpEvVEo07UNwmUmBw5uoHs+dN+fc=", "order"=>{"export"=>"0", "contact"=>"", "exchange_rate"=>"", "fare"=>"", "fee"=>"", "totalprice"=>"", "bank_name"=>"", "bank_account"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Order"}
  Seller Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sellers".* FROM "sellers" WHERE "sellers"."id" = 3 ORDER BY "sellers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.6ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("bank_account", "bank_name", "contact", "created_at", "export", "seller_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["bank_account", ""], ["bank_name", ""], ["contact", ""], ["created_at", Fri, 13 Sep 2013 10:49:37 UTC +00:00], ["export", false], ["seller_id", 3], ["updated_at", Fri, 13 Sep 2013 10:49:37 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.8ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http:// /orders/34
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)


Started GET "/orders/34" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-13 18:49:37 +0800
Processing by OrdersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"34"}
  Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "34"]]
  Seller Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "sellers".* FROM "sellers" WHERE "sellers"."id" = 3 ORDER BY "sellers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered orders/show.html.erb within layouts/application (6.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `product' for #<Order:0x007f97e6365260>):
    15:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name("手續費") %>:</strong></dt>
    16:   <dd><%= @order.fee %></dd>
    17:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name("商品網頁") %>:</strong></dt>
    18:   <dd><%= @order.product.name %></dd>
    19:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name("備註") %>:</strong></dt>
    20:   <dd><%= @order.description %></dd>
    21:   <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name("數量") %>:</strong></dt>
  app/views/orders/show.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_orders_show_html_erb__256659907252631377_70145189586620'


  Rendered /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (11.2ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Order model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, allow_destroy: true
```

And permit `products_attributes: [...]` in `order_params` method

I think, your `order_params` method should looks like this:

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:contact, products_attributes: [:id, :name, :description, :success, :count, :spot, :janpan_price, :taiwan_price, :_destroy ]).merge(:seller_id => current_seller.id)
end
```

Comment: if I used this order_params cause SyntaxError /Users/mac/rails_workspace/superbuy/app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:92: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...rice, :_destroy ]).m... ... ^

Comment: well, I success when I add {}.But I couldn't show   <dd><%= @order.product.name %></dd>

Comment: I think it didn't save, is it for I didn't have order_id in order_params?If so where can I add this?

Comment: u mean sth I put above or??def create ?

Comment: I mean `rails s` log, like: `Started POST "/rentals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-12 18:05:51 +0300`

Comment: => Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-09-13 18:07:24] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-09-13 18:07:24] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
[2013-09-13 18:07:24] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1995 port=3000   this one??

Comment: yup, but i want to see output after creating an order

Comment: `@order.product.name` don't working b/c `order` has_many `products`. If u want to show all order products: @order.products.each { |product| product.name } or @order.products.pluck(:name).join(', ')

Comment: I think, it's b/c this `@order` has no products

Comment: it means I didn't saved success?If so how can I add order_id to the params?or put in the input?I find someone use f.hidden_field,so I need pass order_id via params[:id]?

Comment: Yes. show your actial `order_params` method. I dont see `products_attributes` in server log output. Maybe you forgot to fill product fields on the form?

Comment: params.require(:order).permit(:export, :contact, :exchange_rate, :fare, :fee, {products_attributes: [:id, :name, :description, :success, :count, :spot, :janpan_price, :taiwan_price, :_destroy ]}, :totalprice, :bank_name, :bank_account).merge(:seller_id => current_seller.id)

Comment: Try: `params.require(:order).permit(:export, :contact, :exchange_rate, :fare, :fee, :totalprice, :bank_name, :bank_account, products_attributes: [:id, :name, :description, :success, :count, :spot, :janpan_price, :taiwan_price, :_destroy ]).merge(:seller_id => current_seller.id)`

Comment: I think, problem in order form. Because `products_attributes` parameters doesn't come.

Comment: u mean here??<%= f.simple_fields_for :products do |product| %>
  <%= render 'product_fields', :f => product %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association 'add product', f, :products %>